# How to determine if a Databricks cluster is ready using the API?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I'm calling the /clusters/events API with PowerShell to check if my Databricks cluster is up and ready for the next step in my setup process. Is this the best approach?

Currently, I grab the array of ClusterEvent and check the most recent ClusterEvent for its ClusterEventType. If it's `RUNNING`, we're good to go and we move on to the next step.

Recently, I discovered my release pipeline was hanging while checking the cluster status. It turns out that the cluster was in fact running but its status was `DRIVER_HEALTHY`, not `RUNNNING`. So, I changed my script and everyone is happy again.

Is there an official API call I make that returns yes/no, true/false, etc. so I don't need to code for the ClusterEventType I find means the cluster is running?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such API that says yes/no about the cluster status. You can use [`Get` command of the Clusters REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters.html#get) - it returns information about current state of the cluster, so you just need to wait until it's get to the `RUNNING` state.

P.S. if you're doing that as part of release pipeline, or something like, then you can look to the [Terraform provider for Databricks](https://github.com/databrickslabs/terraform-provider-databricks) - it will handle waiting for cluster running, and other things automatically, and you can combine it with other things, like, provisioning of Azure resources, etc.